# Android Studio doesn't get app is running on emulator or real device

Tags: android, android-studio, android-gradle-plugin, adb

I just installed Android Studio Arctic Fox (2020.3.1) Stable

i opened my project as usual and oponed the emulator to try the app but weirdly android studio doesn't get app is running on emulator, so i tried my real phone yet same result still gives me the green play button even when app is running on emulator, my previous android studio was 4.1.1 and everything was fine, tried to create new emulator device yet still same problem

emulator is pixel 4 XL android 9.0

```
android {
compileSdkVersion 30
buildToolsVersion "30.0.3"

defaultConfig {
    applicationId "com.minidev99.euroimpianti"
    minSdkVersion 24
    targetSdkVersion 30
    versionCode 1
    versionName "1.0"
```

and evenLog show this:

```
bad sub-command
            com.android.ddmlib.CommandFailedException: bad sub-command
            at com.android.ddmlib.EmulatorConsole.processOutput(EmulatorConsole.java:424)
            at com.android.ddmlib.EmulatorConsole.getOutput(EmulatorConsole.java:411)
            at com.android.ddmlib.EmulatorConsole.getAvdPath(EmulatorConsole.java:402)
            at com.android.ddmlib.internal.DeviceMonitor.setProperties(DeviceMonitor.java:296)
            at com.android.ddmlib.internal.DeviceMonitor.updateDevices(DeviceMonitor.java:260)
            at com.android.ddmlib.internal.DeviceMonitor.access$400(DeviceMonitor.java:56)
            at com.android.ddmlib.internal.DeviceMonitor$DeviceListUpdateListener.deviceListUpdate(DeviceMonitor.java:326)
            at com.android.ddmlib.internal.DeviceListMonitorTask.processIncomingDeviceData(DeviceListMonitorTask.java:195)
            at com.android.ddmlib.internal.DeviceListMonitorTask.run(DeviceListMonitorTask.java:131)
            at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:834)
```

Comment: Install new emulator and test if it works or not

Comment: tried , yet didn't work

Comment: Then you should reinstall adb

Comment: how?????? how??????

Comment: https://developer.android.com/studio/command-line/adb

Comment: didn't work...........